# How to add user defined dependency item in dependency file while compiling

Tags: c, makefile

I have these files in the same folder:

```
a.c
b.c
common.c
liba.mk
libb.mk
```

*"liba.mk"* is designated to compile *"a.c"* and *"common.c"* and archive the object files. *"libb.mk"* is doing similar works on *"b.c"* and *"common.c"*

My problem is, *"common.c"* appears at both makefile. How to add dependency rules on this? I expect that when I make *"liba.mk"* and then make *"libb.mk"*, *"libb.mk"* would re-compile *"common.c"*.

Here is my content on liba.mk:

```
SRC_C = a.c common.c
SRC_O = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C))

OBJ_LIST = $(addprefix liba/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C)))
DEPENDENCY_LIST = $(addprefix liba/,$(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC_C)))

all: pre_action liba

.PHONY: pre_action
pre_action:
    mkdir liba

.PHONY: liba
liba: $(SRC_O)
    $(AR) rvs liba/liba.a $(OBJ_LIST)

$(SRC_O): %.o : %.c
    $(CC) -DLIBA -c $< -o $@
    $(CC) -DLIBA -c $< -MM -MT $@ -MF liba/$(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@)
    cp $@ liba/$(notdir $@)

-include $(DEPENDENCY_LIST)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf liba
    rm -f $(SRC_O)
```

And libb.mk has similar content:

```
SRC_C = b.c common.c
SRC_O = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C))

OBJ_LIST = $(addprefix libb/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C)))
DEPENDENCY_LIST = $(addprefix libb/,$(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC_C)))

all: pre_action libb

.PHONY: pre_action
pre_action:
    mkdir libb

.PHONY: libb
libb: $(SRC_O)
    $(AR) rvs libb/libb.a $(OBJ_LIST)

$(SRC_O): %.o : %.c
    $(CC) -DLIBB -c $< -o $@
    $(CC) -DLIBB -c $< -MM -MT $@ -MF libb/$(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@)
    cp $@ libb/$(notdir $@)

-include $(DEPENDENCY_LIST)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf libb
    rm -f $(SRC_O)
```

I guess that I need to append extra dependency item when generating dependency file. But it seems silly to perform file processing on dependency file. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Probably it will not recompile `common.c` when it sees that all the dependencies of `common.c` are older than `common.o`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I need `libb.mk` to recompile `common.c` because libb.mk use different compile flag.

Comment: Then what problem are you trying to solve? I advise you to give the two versions of `common.o` different names (e.g. `common_a.o` and `common_b.o`), but I can't tell whether that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I now understand that you MUST recompile `common.c` because it uses different compiler flags (`-DLIBB` vs. `-DLIBA`) and, since the dependencies of `common.o` (i.e. `common.c` and possibly header files) did not change it did not recompile `common.c`.

To achieve that you could use:

```
pre_action:
    rm common.o
    mkdir libb          # or liba
```

My `make` is a bit rusty but I believe this will always compile `common.c`.